# Search Spiders Crashing Apache

Tags: php, apache, webserver, error-log, access-log

My webserver is frequently crashing, and I've noticed that it always occurs after this error log entry:

```
[Sun Jun 22 00:41:41 2014] [error] [client 207.46.13.71] File does not exist: C:/*directory*/robots.txt
```

I know this IP belongs to a Bing spider. From my understanding, upon failing to find an instance of robots.txt, Bing will try to index my site. I believe while it's trying to index my site, the issue which is causing the crash occurs.

My problem is that am not able to recreate or locate the issue. My access logs don't seem to be showing which files Bing is trying to index, or which script are causing the server to crash. I've taken a few stabs in the dark by passing invalid or no information to certain scripts, but so far I haven't been able to find anything broken.

Can anyone explain to me what other options I might have in trying to find which script is causing my webserver to crash?

I'm running Apache/2.2.17 using XAMPP on a Windows machine.

Comment: If your Apache logs aren't showing any records of Bing spidering your site, how do you know it's causing it to crash?

Comment: Why do you not have a robots.txt file?

Comment: Anders, sorry, I really didn't think that was relevant. I edited that information in.

@LukePeterson The crashes have occurred periodically over the course of a few days. EVERY crash has directly preceded by Bing trying to access 'robots.txt'.

Comment: Have you tried just creating the robots.txt file?  Or even adding a directive there to prevent Bing from crawling? (even temporarily)

Comment: @MikeBrant I hardly think creating a robots.txt file is the proper solution to a buggy script that's crashing my webserver. I'll create it after I've solved this issue.

Comment: @LukePeterson I considered it, but that seems like a bandaid that does nothing to solve my problem. See my reply above.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have a robots.txt you're basically telling Bingbot it's ok to crawl as much of your site as fast as it can.  Something like:

```
User-agent: bingbot
Disallow:
Crawl-delay: 10
```

Will go a long way to helping you understand why it's failing.  Not having a robots.txt because it 'sounds like a bandaid' I think is the wrong approach.

Comment: I guess I had a misunderstanding of what robots.txt was used for; I didn't know it had this kind of functionality. I'll give this a shot, thanks!

Comment: No worries, good luck. ;)  I'd be very interested to know what else you discover.

Comment: I'll be sure to post the cause of the problem when I figure it out. Right now I'm just waiting playing the waiting game. Are there any tools available that I can use to manually scan my site the way a search index would?

Comment: Yes, give [Xenu](http://home.snafu.de/tilman/xenulink.html) a go.  It's not the prettiest tool but I've been using it for years for this exact scenario. ;)